# Find Text tag with content in Enzyme

Tags: javascript, react-native, enzyme

I have the following React Native code in a component called `MyComponent`:

```
<Text> {Constants.MY_TEXT} </Text>
```

I am trying to test it like this with enzyme:

```
const wrapper = shallow(
            <MyComponent/>
        );
expect(wrapper.find(<Text> {Constants.MY_TEXT} </Text>)).toHaveLength(1);
```

However, the test fails because `0` occurrences of `<Text> {Constants.MY_TEXT} </Text>` are found.

I think this is because `wrapper.find` does not understand the argument I am passing to it.

I also tried searching just for the text, without the tag:

```
expect(wrapper.find({Constants.MY_TEXT})).toHaveLength(1);
```

However, this fails with:

```
Unexpected token, expected ,
```

Any idea how to make the test see the `Text` tag?

Answer (score 3):

For enzyme find api -> [doc](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/find.html), it only support find a `Component constructor` or `Component name`.

So try to use this way:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent/>);
expect(wrapper.find(Text)).toHaveLength(1);
```

If you want to test `text`, they also provide [text api](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/text.html)